# Constructing proximity matrix in Wolfram Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolfram-language

I have the following dataset:

```
dataset = 
Dataset[{<|"City" -> "Belgrade" , "Population" -> 1500000|>, <|
"City" -> "Ljubljana", "Population" -> 300000|>, <|
"City" -> "Sarajevo", "Population" -> 275000|>, <|
"City" -> "Zagreb", "Population" -> 800000|>, <|
"City" -> "Skopje", "Population" -> 530000|>, <|
"City" -> "Podgorica", "Population" -> 180000|>}]
```

I want to construct proximity matrix out of it, using Euclidean Distance (function in Wolfram Mathematica: EuclideanDistance) between the city populations. I had some trials but it didn't work out in the end. Anyone has an idea?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
pop=Normal[dataset[All,"Population"]];
MatrixPlot[Outer[Sqrt[(#1-#2)^2]&,pop,pop]]
```

which I think implements EuclidianDistance

Answer (score 1):

Adding `FrameTicks` and using `EuclideanDistance`.

```
pop = Normal[dataset[All, "Population"]];
cities = Normal[dataset[All, "City"]];
ticks = List @@@ Thread[Range@Length@cities -> (Style[#, 14, Black] &) /@ cities]

MatrixPlot[Outer[EuclideanDistance[##] &, pop, pop],
 FrameTicks -> {ticks, ticks, ticks, ticks},
 Mesh -> True,
 MeshStyle -> Black,
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]